# Correct pyhidapi version not found while trying to install emokit

Tags: conda, emokit

I'm trying to install `emokit` on OS X 10.12.5 machine. When I try to do it with either `pip` or `pip3`, I get the following error:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ Joonas$ pip3 install emokit
Collecting emokit
  Using cached emokit-0.0.8.tar.gz
Collecting pycrypto==2.6.1 (from emokit)
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting future (from emokit)
  Using cached future-0.16.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyhidapi (from emokit)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhidapi (from emokit) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyhidapi (from emokit)
```

It looks like a there should be a list of versions after the second-to-last line. Does this indicate that there's something wrong with emokit or is it something I could fix?

Thanks!